# php - Display popup by comparing user's last login with current time

Tags: php, jquery, session, datetime, popup

I have the following php code, which gets a user's last login time(using session) and compares it with the current time. Let's say if the user's last login was on Saturday and today is Sunday, the popup should appear when the same user logs in:

```
$time = date(RELEASE_NOTICE_DATE, time());
        $show_popup = false;
        $content    =   '';
      if($_POST['login_popup'] == "Y" || $_POST['WhatsNew'] == "Y")
      {
            if (strtotime($time) > strtotime($this->user->last_login) && $_SESSION['whatnewConfig']!=1) {
                $_SESSION['whatnewConfig']=1;
                $show_popup = true;
            } else{
                echo "no";
            }
      }
```

Where RELEASE_NOTICE_DATE is a fixed date(4/23/15 in my case) and 'login_popup' and 'WhatsNew' are 2 buttons(each on different pages) which display the popup on clicking.

My Jquery code for reference:

```
$jQ(document).ready(function(){
var pars="login_popup=Y";
   $jQ.post("/Bids/whatsnew",pars,function(result){
       if(result=="no"){
        return false;   
       }else{
           var bsdPFA= BootstrapDialog.show({title:'What\'s New?', message:result, nl2br:false, draggable:true, buttons:[{label:'Close', id: 'wn_close', action:function(dialogRef){dialogRef.close();}}]});
           bsdPFA.$modal.find('.modal-dialog').css({'width':'60%','height':'auto'});
       }
   });
```

This code is not working properly though. Sometimes the popup appears, sometimes it won't. Please help.

Comment: where is your javascript code

Comment: @xNeyte Just edited the question to include it. Please have a look...